How can I expand the range for a code? How to create a proper loop?
I have a code that is doing what I want, but now it works only for one column of the sheet and I would like to create a loop that will works on multiple columns.
Now the code is checking if column L (12) was edited and if yes, then it takes some values from that column and write them to separate sheet starting from A4.
So my goal is to loop through multiple columns L, N, P etc and then if edited take specific values from that columns (rows are always the same) and write them to another sheet.
I also want to make it write values from separate columns to different ranges. For example values from　column L write to A4 and values from column N to  T4
Is this possible to achieve?　
(code works onEdit)
function checkValues(e) {
var sheetName = "CheckingSheet";
  var columnToWatch = 12; // Column L
  var targetSheetName = "ResultSheet";
  var targetRangeStart = "A4"; // Start writing from B4
  
  var range = e.range;
  var editedSheet = range.getSheet().getName();
  var editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  
  if (editedSheet === sheetName && editedColumn === columnToWatch && range.getBackground() === '#fff2cc') {

    var now = new Date();
    var timestamp = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
    var valuesToRecord = [];
    
    // Get the sheet object by name
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
    
    // Define the cells to read from Sheet1
    var cellAddresses = ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"];
    
    // Loop through cell addresses and get values from sheet
    for (var i = 0; i < cellAddresses.length; i++) {
      var value = sheet.getRange(cellAddresses[i]).getValue();
      valuesToRecord.push(value);
    }
    
   // Get the target sheet
    var targetSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
    
    // Find the last row with content in column A
    var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    
    // Append new data to the next row
    targetSheet.getRange("A" + (lastRow + 1)).setValue(timestamp); // Column A
    targetSheet.getRange("B" + (lastRow + 1)).setValue(valuesToRecord[0]); // Column B
    targetSheet.getRange("C" + (lastRow + 1)).setValue(valuesToRecord[1]); // Column C
    targetSheet.getRange("D" + (lastRow + 1)).setValue(valuesToRecord[2]); // Column D
    targetSheet.getRange("E" + (lastRow + 1)).setValue(valuesToRecord[3]); // Column E
  }
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. About For example values from column L write to A4 and values from column N to T4, in your question, it seems that you want to check "columns L, N, P". In this case, when column "P" is edited, what result do you want? And, in your script, it seems that you want to append the values to the target sheet. But, from your question, you want to always put the values from row 4. Is my understanding correct?

Actually, i have 12 columns to check. I want to keep row appending but values from different columns must go to separate ranges so thats why column L values starts in A4 and appends new result and the values from column N goes to T4 and values from Column P starts from AL4

I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. By the way, about var cellAddresses = ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"];, in your situation, do you want to use the same cells for all edited columns?

so to say it in simple words
①if yellow cells from column L will be edited
②then take values ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"]
③and write the to separate sheet
only column will change so for column N the cellAddresses will be ["N9", "N11", "N15", "N23"]

Thank you for replying. About yellow of if yellow cells from column L will be edited, in the case of column "N", what color do you want to use? And, in your situation, you want to always put the values from row 4. Is my understanding correct?

#fff2cc　I have this color in the code so I would like to keep it. Yes, always start from Row 4 Colum 〇〇 and then append every next result

Thank you for replying. From #fff2cc　I have this color in the code so I would like to keep it., I understood about the backgound color you want to check. About Yes, always start from Row 4 Colum 〇〇 and then append every next result, for example, when column "L" is edited for the first time, you want to put the values of ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"] to cells "A4:E4". And when column "L" is edited again, you want to put the same values to cells "A4:E4" by overwriting. Is my understanding correct?

when column "L" is edited for the first time, I want to put the values of ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"] to cells "A4:E4". And when column "L" is edited again, you want to put the same values to cells "A5:E5". With every edit I want to append a row, so editing for the third time will write values to "A6:E6"

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understand that you wanted to append the values to the target sheet. In that case, for example, when column "L" is edited for the first time, you want to put the values of ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"] to cells "A4:E4". Then, when column "N" is edited for the first time, where cells do you want to put the values ["N9", "N11", "N15", "N23"] in?

["N9", "N11", "N15", "N23"]　goes to T4

Thank you for replying. About ["N9", "N11", "N15", "N23"]　goes to T4, in this case, you want to check the last row of each output column? For example, when column "L" is edited, and column "N" is edited, and column "L" is edited again, you want to put the values of ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"] into "A5:E5". Is my understanding correct?

yes you are correct

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize. And, I cannot know your actual situation. If this script cannot be used, please provide a sample Spreadsheet including your expected result. By this, I would like to confirm it.

I believe your goal is as follows.

You want to run the script in the if statement when the background of #fff2cc and columns "L", "N", and "P" are edited.
When column "L" is edited for the first time, you want to put the values ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"] into "A4:E4" as append. And, when column "L" is edited, you want to put the values ["L9", "L11", "L15", "L23"] into "A4:E4". You want to append each value to the last row of each target column.

From your question and script, I guessed that your function checkValues has already been installed as the OnEdit trigger. Please be careful about this.
In this case, how about the following sample script?
Sample script:
Before you use this script, please set your values to obj. In the current obj, var obj = { "12": 1, "14": 20, "16": 38 }; is used. This means that columns "L", "N", and "P" are edited, and the values are put into columns "A", "T", and "AL", respectively. This is from your following comment.

Actually, i have 12 columns to check. I want to keep row appending but values from different columns must go to separate ranges so thats why column L values starts in A4 and appends new result and the values from column N goes to T4 and values from Column P starts from AL4

function checkValues(e) {
  // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44563639
  Object.prototype.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom = function (columnNumber, offsetRow = 1) {
    const search = this.getRange(offsetRow, columnNumber, this.getMaxRows()).createTextFinder(".").useRegularExpression(true).findPrevious();
    return search ? search.getRow() : offsetRow;
  };

  var sheetName = "CheckingSheet";
  var obj = { "12": 1, "14": 20, "16": 38 }; // Columns L -> A, N -> T, P -> AL
  var targetSheetName = "ResultSheet";
  var { range, source } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() === sheetName && obj[range.columnStart] && range.getBackground() === '#fff2cc') {
    var now = new Date();
    var timestamp = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
    var sheet = source.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    var rowNumbers = [9, 11, 15, 23];
    var rowValues = sheet.getRange(1, range.columnStart, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var valuesToRecord = [[timestamp, ...rowNumbers.map(e => rowValues[e - 1][0])]];
    var targetSheet = source.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
    var maxCol = targetSheet.getMaxColumns();
    if (maxCol < obj[range.columnStart]) {
      targetSheet.insertColumns(maxCol, obj[range.columnStart] - maxCol);
    }
    var lastRow = targetSheet.get1stNonEmptyRowFromBottom(obj[range.columnStart]);
    targetSheet.getRange(lastRow < 4 ? 4 : lastRow + 1, obj[range.columnStart], 1, valuesToRecord[0].length).setValues(valuesToRecord);
  }
}


When I tested this script, I thought that when I could correctly understand your expected result, your expected result would be obtained.

I think that in this case, the function name onEdit can also be used.



It works perfect! Thank you!

@Timonek About It works perfect! Thank you!, welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
